# How do I check what currency a fund is denominated in?

Tags: currency

VXUS is a international stock ETF, but I purchase in USD. I was under the impression that it was denominated in foreign currencies, as I was partially trying to diversify against domestic currency risk as well as economic.

How can I verify if the fund is denominated in foreign currencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I verify if the fund is denominated in foreign currencies?

The [Product Information Page](https://institutional.vanguard.com/web/cfv/product-details/fund/3369) lists all of the currencies that the fund has securities in. The fund itself trades in USD as you mentioned, so there is currency risk inherent in the fund (securities can lose value because of changes in currency value unrelated to the performance of the stocks)

Comment: The currency risk in a fund comes from the currencies of the assets held in the fund, not from the currency in which it is traded.